# being able to read a file on command file using java

Tags: java, command-prompt

I have a program that works fine when it is run on eclipse (the program reads from a text file). However when it is complied and run on command line it can not find the text file I am reading from.

```
private void openfile()
{
    try
    {
        file = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("i hate command prompt");
    }

private void readfile()
{
    while(file.hasNext())
    {
            map_name = file.nextLine().split("\\s+");

    }
}

private void closefile()
{
    file.close();
}
```

can anyone explain how i can avoid this

Comment: Is the text file in the same directory as your class?

Answer (score 0):

You must place `file.txt` in the `user.dir` as specified by the [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) documentation.  To determine what the `user.dir` is try printing out the property in your code, then placing the file in the directory.

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

Comment: They have the same directory